# How to find rotation of an object within an ROI in template matching?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing, emgucv

Im trying to inspect the connector pins in a charger. The job is to inspect these parameters :

1. both pins are present
2. Both are of defined height
3. Both are straight

I used template matching in C# & EMGU to extract a template by creating an roi and after matching it checks whether both pins are present using following code for each pins:

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> templateImage = pintofind;
      
  Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(GrabImage.Bitmap);
       
        using (Image<Gray, float> imgMatch = sourceImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))
        {            

            Point[] MAX_Loc, Min_Loc;
            double[] min, max;
            imgMatch.MinMax(out min, out max, out Min_Loc, out MAX_Loc);

            using (Image<Gray, double> RG_Image = imgMatch.Convert<Gray, double>().Copy())
            {                    
                    if (max[0] > 0.75)
                {
                    Rectangle match = new Rectangle(MAX_Loc[0], templateImage.Size);
                    sourceImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.LimeGreen), 2);

                    lblresulttext.Text = "OK";
                    lbindgood.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    Rectangle match = new Rectangle(MAX_Loc[0], templateImage.Size);
                    sourceImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    lblresulttext.Text = "NG";
                    lbindbad.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
            ibresult.Image = sourceImage;
        }
```

This is the result I get:

[image: okpins]

It works well to check the presence of pins, but now I need to check if both are of same height and if both are straight like this image below:

[image: ngpins]

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure MatchTemplate is the correct approach if you want to identify the specific failure. It might be usable if you are guaranteed a consistent rotation, and only need to check if the actual image is the same as the template. But if you need to measure the length or identify specific failures you might need a template for each kind of failure, and that might not be feasible.

I would approach this problem by thresholding the image to separate the background from the foreground. Presumably you have control over the lighting to make this fairly simple. You should then be able to use the [contour features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to find the position and rotation of the charger. You should then be able to compare this to a reference contour, see [MatchShapes](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.0/document/html/1a578a07-1f9e-c3c7-2b88-3a4c326141d7.htm). You will probably need some way to isolate the pins if they are the important part, for example by finding the rotated bounding box of the charger, and ignore everything except the top part that contain the pins.

Answer (score 0):

If you can process the rotation of the charger, I think that using 2 templates is better than using one template.
The first template might be the top part of the pin and the second template might be the bottom part of the pin. After detecting the 2 pairs of top and bottom part of the pins, you can measure the height and direction of the pins.

[image]